# Ubuntu 14.10 and Macbook pro 6,1 and the touchpad

Tags: 14.10, touchpad, macbook-pro

I have an irritating bug where I seem to get the program selector popping up all the time with the touchpad.  I think it is triggered with the 3 finger double tap, but appear somehow at random times.  Is there anyway of tweaking or disabling it within Ubuntu?

Otherwise its a flawless system :D

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by manually editing the file

```
/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf
```

If its not there, create one

```
vi /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf
```

But you should read this link [Synaptic touchpad](https://wiki.debian.org/SynapticsTouchpad) before starting.

For more info on this, see the manual

```
man synaptics
```